# How to show custom attributes of customer in separate/new tab

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I have created couple of attributes for customer and new tab in customer edit form of customer for backend. Currently custom attributes are appearing in Account Information tab. Can i change the tab for these custom attributes?

It may be the duplicate of some other question, but i couldn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: Ever find the answer to this? looking for something similar

Comment: Was able to create a custom tab in customer detail page but couldn't display custom attributes in it.

Comment: Do you find the solution

Comment: Nothing yet @Jaisa